# Converting uint8_t and uint16_t to NSMutableData

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I am fairly new to programming and I am trying to develop a bluetooth fitness device using CoreBluetooth for iOS. I bought a bunch of different devices from different hardware manufacturers for testing and one of the instructions for sending values to the device

I want to be able to write a value (fitness goal) to the Bluetooth fitness device. I know how to read/write with Bluetooth.

I just don't know how to convert the values I want to uint8_t and uint16_t and then combine it into an 8 byte NSMutableData.

Can anyone tell me how I would do this?

Comment: NS(Mutable)Data is just an encapsulated form of a byte array.  You need to convert your values into byte sequences.  (You do know how to use shift and mask operations in C, right?)

Comment: You should.  Objective-C is not for beginners.  You need to learn C first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing to worry about is byte ordering. It doesn't matter for the `uint8_t` but it matters for anything larger. You can have big-endian or little-endian. Check the docs for device.

Start with your values:

```
uint8_t days = 12;
uint16_t walked = 225;
uint16_t ran = 110
uint16_t steps = 750;
uint8_t users = 2;

NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
[data appendBytes:&days length:1];
uint16_t network = CFSwapInt16HostToBig(walked);
[data appendBytes:&network length:2];
network = CFSwapInt16HostToBig(ran);
[data appendBytes:&network length:2];
network = CFSwapInt16HostToBig(steps);
[data appendBytes:&network length:2];
[data appendBytes:&users length:1];
```

The above assumes you need the data in big-endian format. If it need to be little-endian then change `CFSwapInt16HostToBig` to `CFSwapInt16HostToLittle`.

Comment: Thank you so much rmaddy! This definitely helped.  It is transmitting to the device except the the distance walked, ran, and steps are off. The users and days are good (the uint8_t values). it is displaying walked value as: 025 ran as: 210 and steps as: 150. I am guessing the order for those is just off. I tried the HostToLittle but not luck either. Any other suggestions? Thanks again :)

Comment: What values do you see with `HostToLittle`?

Comment: For HostToLittle, walked = 000, ran = 666, steps= 130. Thanks!

Comment: Neither makes any sense. If it was a simple matter of using the wrong byre ordering, the wrong order would probably give numbers that were way off but both sets of numbers are similar. Are you sure there's no typo in your code and are you sure that is the proper sequence of if bytes and it's really 8 bytes? What about units? Distance could be a feet/meters issue maybe. But that doesn't explain the step count. I don't think there is a problem with imperial/metric counts. :)